# How to hide grid columns effectively

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a very large grid with many columns. When the user clicks on the button, it calls a function which analyzes the whole store - cell by cell, if it finds no changes in a particular column, it hides it, othewise the column stays visible. Very often quite a large number of columns get hidden, but as I can see, this operation - column hiding with all this rendering - is very "heavy", so that my browser may alert, that the code runs for too long. 
I do hiding like this:

```
var cols=grid.headerCt.getGridColumns(); 
Ext.each(cols, function (item, index, all){
  if(condition) item.setVisible(false); 
});
```

I tried to use `Ext.suspendLayouts()` and `Ext.resumeLayouts()`, but it leads to a bug. Even though operation now runs faster, instead of column hiding only columns' titles get hidden. So, I need a more optimal and working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suspendLayouts() and subsequent resumeLayouts() is one of the ways to go. You only need to call `grid.getView().refresh()` after you resume the layouts.

Another option would be to call reconfigure, however, this removes the "hidden" columns from the columns menu.